# npm error - verify that the package.json has a valid "main" entry

Tags: node.js

Im playing around with a simple trading bot using binance and cctx

when i run my script with `node index.js`

i get this long error:

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:323
      throw err;
      ^

Error: Cannot find module '/home/ether/Documents/nodesendeth/node_modules/cctx/index.js'. Please verify that the package.json has a valid "main" entry
    at tryPackage (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:315:19)
    at Function.Module._findPath (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:703:18)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:967:27)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:862:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1040:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ether/Documents/nodesendeth/index.js:2:14)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1151:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1171:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1000:32) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  path: '/home/ether/Documents/nodesendeth/node_modules/cctx/package.json',
  requestPath: 'cctx'
}
```

so it basically cant find the cctx module
cctx was installed with `npm i cctx` and i also ran `npm install` afterwards just to make sure.

It also says verify that package.json file has a valid main entry, which it does:

```
{
  "name": "nodesendeth",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "cctx": "^1.0.1",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0"
  }
}
```

I pasted the code to my script here
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/p4n6MH3vbn/

Also my await functions arent working- even though i use them in an async function

So Im not a 100% sure what exactly the error is, there is a main entry in the package.json file and the cctx module has been installed

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Uo3cL4nrGOk&t=18s

Answer (score 120):

Remove your node_modules folder and run `npm i`

Comment: for my case it turns out to be the pacakge i was trying installed is deprecated, and in npm's warning log, it tells me to install a non-deprecated replacement pacakge i.e. loadsh -> lodash

Answer (score 24):

1. Delete node_modules
2. Run "npm i"
3. Fixed

For me, the cause was that I accidentally hit STRG + C while installing all the modules, which broke something.

Answer (score 9):

If you are working with firebase functions, and you are using TypeScript, check the path to the generated index.js after `npm run build`.

In my case it was lib/functions/src/main.js.

setting:

```
"main": "lib/functions/src/index.js",
```

on `package.json` fixed the issue

Answer (score 7):

I have also faced the same Problem earlier.
I solved the problem by deleting the **node_modules** folder and then

```
npm update
```

then

```
npm install
```

Comment: To be on safe side: ```npm update --legacy-peer-deps``` & ```npm install --legacy-peer-deps```

Answer (score 6):

Run `npm update`, it will fix the issue

Or you can also delete `node_modules` and the `package-lock.json` file then `npm install` will also solve the issue.

Answer (score 3):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cctx <- Not a valid package. It's a typo for this package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ccxt (CCXT instead of CCTX). Install that instead. The issue isn't with your code, it's that you installed the wrong package.

Comment: ok, thanks dude, this happens to me all the time that i dont catch those stupid typos, however even after i fix it i get an error that config is not defined even though i defined it

Comment: I would refer to the docs and/or create another question if you're stuck. I'm not intimately familiar with that package but someone else may be.

Answer (score 3):

If you are working with firebase functions, and you are using TypeScript,

run the
`npm run build`
inside the Function directory

after that, a folder is generated in the current folder **lib**

then return back and fire!

```
$ firebase deploy
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was getting this error from my VS Code ESLint plugin output. However running the linter through the terminal was just fine. After exhausting other options, restarting VS Code did the trick and ESLint plugin runs.